# Creating the Enterprise addin Using java

Tags: enterprise-architect

Can the Addin for the EA can be created using Java plugin development. If yes how can we register the addin written in java to the EA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Create Enterprise Archetict Extensions using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288883/is-it-possible-to-create-enterprise-archetict-extensions-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create DLL that can be COM registered for EA to be able to communicate with the add-in.

There might be workarounds using tools that can somehow create those dll's from Java code, but without jumping though (a lot of) hoops the answer is negative.